# Is this inverse limit of groups of roots of unity the Prüfer group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and for each $n\geq 0$, let $\mu_{p^{n}}$ denote the group of $p^{n}$-th complex roots of $1$.

Let us say that $n\leq m$ if $n$ divides $m$. If this is the case, we have a homomorphism
\begin{equation}
\varphi_{mn}
\colon\mu_{p^{m}}\to\mu_{p^{n}},\qquad\qquad \zeta\mapsto \zeta^{\frac{m}{n}}
\end{equation}
which satisfies $\varphi_{ca}=\varphi_{ba}\circ\varphi_{cb}$ whenever $a\leq b\leq c$ and $\varphi_{ii}=1$ for any $i\geq 0$.

In other words, this forms an inverse system.

Considering each finite group $\mu_{p^{n}}$ as a discrete space, we then can take the inverse limit.

My question is:

> Is this inverse limit the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group)?

I suspect it is, but I didn't found any characterization of the latter as this limit, so I'm not sure.

Thanks! Any tips on how to prove this will be appreciated.

Comment: The Prufer group is definitely the colimit (direct limit) over the diagram that has these groups as objects and the inclusions as morphisms. I don't know about your question, but my guess would be not.

Comment: For possible context, an inverse limit like this appears in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a rather more advanced take on your question than is necessary to answer it.

It all has an origin in the field $\Bbb Q_p$ of $p$-adic numbers. Just considering the additive structure, $\Bbb Q_p$ has an important compact subgroup $\Bbb Z_p$, and the quotient $\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p$ can be seen to be countable, indeed the union of the subgroups $\left(\frac1{p^n}\Bbb Z_p\right)\big/\Bbb Z_p$. each of the limiting groups is cyclic, of order $p^n$, and that limit is the Prüfer group.

The subgroup $\Bbb Z_p\subset\Bbb Q_p$ can be looked at as the inverse limit of the groups $\Bbb Z_p/p^n\Bbb Z_p\cong\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$. This is your group.

Comment: Somehow the fact that roots of unity form cyclic groups was lost in my mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The direct limit of the groups $\mu_{p^n} \simeq \mathbb{Z} /p^n \mathbb {Z}$ (which is just the union of the $\mu_{p^n} $) is the Prüfer. But the inverse limit you're considering is the group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of $p$-adic integers. It is an uncountable  group in which $\mathbb{Z}$ can be embedded (two reasons why it can't be isomorphic to the Prüfer group).

Comment: In general, you can expect the inverse limit of finite groups to be uncountable (if not finite!), and the direct limit to be countable. Since the Prüfer group is countable, this general principle suggests that it’s not any kind of inverse limit.